# Determining all sub-vector combinations of a binary vector for a certain hamming weight

Tags: java, python, c++

Given a binary vector *x*, and a number *y* which is less than the hamming weight of this binary vector, I want to return the set of vectors of the same size as *x*, which are contained within *x* with hamming weight *y*.

For instance, the binary vector '0110110' with the y value 3, should return

- 0110100
- 0110010
- 0100110
- 0010110

The same vector with y value 2 should return

- 0110000
- 0100100
- 0100010
- 0010100
- 0010010
- 0000110

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! 
I use python but an example in any similar language would be great. (C/Java etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this problem is to fetch all the non zero element indexes and thereby find a combinations of size `y`, of all these indexes.

For example:

binary vector: `'0110110'` with y = `3`, 
indexes would be (1,2,4,5)
and the combinations of size `y = 3` would be  `indexes = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 5)]`

Now it would be trivial to iterate through the above combinations and toggle off the element indexed by each item of the above list

```
for i in index:
    binary_seq[i] = '0'
```

**Implementation**

```
def foo(bin_seq, y):
    from itertools import combinations
    bin_seq = list(bin_seq)
    y = bin_seq.count('1') - y
    indexes = [i for i in range(len(bin_seq)) if bin_seq[i] == '1']
    for index in combinations(indexes,  y):
        vec = bin_seq[:]
        for i in index:
            vec[i] = '0'
        yield ''.join(vec)
```

**Example**

```
>>> list(foo('0110110', 3))
['0010110', '0100110', '0110010', '0110100']
>>> list(foo('0110110', 2))
['0000110', '0010010', '0010100', '0100010', '0100100', '0110000']
```